# How to draw an animated chart in WPF

Tags: animation, charts, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0, amcharts

In my WPF application, I need to draw a line chart which draws a line with an animation. The best solution I've found yet, is to use Devexpress tool which provide all what I need and much more but it's quite expensive and I guess it won't fit my budget.

I also tried to do it with WPF toolkit and AMChart but I can't find any way to animate the drawing of the line on the chart.

Is it possible to set an animation or to create one and assign it to chart (from WPF toolkit or Amchart) ?

The aim is to draw the line like if I was drawing it slowly on the chart.

For this project I'm using Visual Studio 2012, WPF, .NET 4.0, C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animation Libraries that exist in WPF. For example by using DoubleAnimation, you can do any animation at your project.